Change passkey order or remove mobile device in Windows passkey popup
I use Yubikey and sometimes Windows Hello but never use "iphone/android devices".
So it's annoying to see multiple options and even worse when my preferred option is not top of the list.
I need any of the following feature:

Auto-select Windows Hello and security key from the list.

Remove iphone from the list

Move security key to the top of the list




There is no way to remove the option or change the order at this time.

1. Open Registry Editor:
Press Win + R, type regedit, and press Enter.
2. Navigate to the FIDO Key:
Go to HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\FIDO.
3. Delete the Device Key:
Find the folder with the unique ID of your device and delete it.

This solution works. I can confirm it personally, cause it helped in my case :-D
I don't see any reason to citate any documents for that, stupid bot :-P
